# How can I set Variable score1 and score2 in if k2.value() == 0:

Tags: python

I  want to clear variable `score1` and `score2` in `if k2.value() == 0`:

[image]

Comment: As stated in [ask], *DO NOT post images of code, (...) copy or type the text into the question.*

Comment: Wouldn't you just want score1=0 in addition to lcd.clear() in the condition under k2.value() == 0 ?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but what keeps you from writing `score1 = 0` and `score2 = 0` under the if-statement?

Comment: Thx a lot guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write

```py
score1, score2 = 0, 0
```

under your `if` statement.

As a side note, you can shorten your `score1 = score1 + 1` to `score1 += 1`. It is also considered more pythonic.

Comment: I complete it thanks